# RPM technique for handling cumulative updates?

Tags: database, upgrade, rpm

RPM seems to be pretty good at checking dependencies and handling individual file updates, but what is the best practice for handling cumulative updates to, say, a relational database across multiple versions?

For instance, say you have product Foo with versions 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, and 1.3.0.  In each of these, there were database schema changes that required SQL upgrade scripts.  Running each upgrade script in sequence is required to get up to the current version of the schema.

Say a customer has 1.2.2 installed and wants to upgrade to 1.3.0.  How can one structure the RPM package so that you have the appropriate scripts available and execute the correct upgrade scripts against the database?  In this instance, you'd want to execute the upgrade scripts for 1.2.3 and 1.3.0, but not the ones for 1.2.1 or 1.2.2. since those have presumably already been executed.

One alternative is to require upgrading to each intermediate version in sequence, forcing the user in this example to upgrade to 1.2.3 before 1.3.0.  This seems less than optimal.  Also, this would presumably need to be "forced" through external process, since I don't see anything in the RPM SPEC file that would indicate this.

Are there any known techniques for handling this?  A bit of Googling didn't expose any.

EDIT:  By "known", I mean "tried and proven" not theoretical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the right tool for the job. RPM probably isn't the right tool.  Something like Liquibase would be better suited to this task.